# Is there any way to stop/interrupt a CSS3 transition animation in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, css, transition

I am using FF version 13.0 and have a transition animation set to occur on :hover. I would like the element to return to it's original state as soon as I am no longer hovering.  But what happens is the element continues to animate until it reaches it's end destination and then returns to it's original state.  In Chrome/Safari (webkit) the elements behave as intended.  I have created a very basic jsfiddle as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/isbhod/YvMJz/

Thank you!

Comment: it seems to be something with the "position: absolute" style on the ".storyHolder:hover" that prevents the css3 transition from being interrupted.  When I remove that style the animation stops when the mouse is moved off the element.  As to how or why I do not know.  I would greatly appreciated some assistance on this.  thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out: for reason unknown , the element that is being hovered on needs to have the same position style before during and after the hover event for it not to fubar the CSS3 transition in FireFox.  I have removed the JS fiddle, but not like anyone saw this anyway.